# How to enable bluetooth HCI trace log in Android4.3

Tags: android, bluetooth, hci

How to enable bluetooth HCI trace log in Android4.3?
in Android4.1, hcidump was used to capture HCI log, but there was no hcidump in 4.3.

Comment: hcidump was part of bluez stack which is replaced by bluedroid in 4.3, bluedroid will have different tracer mechanism